# How dependency injection in Spring is working in this statement?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm learning about dependency injection in Spring and I have this code:

```
    @Autowired
    private CamelContext context;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext createCamelContext(){

        return context;
    }

    ...
}
```

I understand that context and environment bean is injected in this class, but what I don't understand is what exactly is injected with this code:

```
@Autowired
protected CamelContext createCamelContext(){

    return context;
}
```

I don't understand this kind of injection. What exactly is happen here? What is the difference between this method injection and this simple method without injection:

```
protected CamelContext createCamelContext(){

    return context;
}
```

Any feedback will be apreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, `@Autowired` is pretty much equivalent to `@Bean` on `createCamelContext` and `@Inject` on `context`. [Autowiring beans occurs by type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57894914/5699679) if you don't give a `@Qualifier`, so your code will basically take your `@Autowired/@Inject CamelContext context` and go looking for a `CamelContext` to fill in the missing value, which it will find as provided by `@Autowired/@Bean createCamelContext`.

The difference between an annotated `createCamelContext` and an un-annotated one is that Spring will not have that method in its Beans, and so it won't find the method when looking for a `@Bean` to `@Inject`.

In your specific case, the value `context` goes looking for a `CamelContext`, and finds one in the form of `createCamelContext`. At this point, `createCamelContext` looks up the value of `context`, which is `null`. It returns this value, which is injected into `context`. Therefore, at any point in time, referring to `context` or `createCamelContext` should always yield `null`.

Comment: This answer pretty much describes what the code is doing - if you want a deeper understanding of what `@Bean`, `@Autowired`, and `@Inject` actually are, take a look at the [Spring guides](https://spring.io/guides) and [Kirill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58382526/5699679).

Answer (score 0):

Methods annotaded with `@Autowired` are either setters or config methods. They are called after bean creation and can be used for initialization. All the arguments of these methods will be automatically injected by Spring. From Spring [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html):

> **Autowired Methods**
>
> Config methods may have an arbitrary name and any
>   number of arguments; each of those arguments will be autowired with a
>   matching bean in the Spring container. Bean property setter methods
>   are effectively just a special case of such a general config method.
>   Such config methods do not have to be public.

But in your case `createCamelContext()` has no arguments and does no initialization either. So I don't see any reason to declare this method.

Comment: I agree that having `@Autowired` seems weird and out of place in this particular case.